# How to capture sound output from PC game in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, capture

I am trying to create a game capture software.
I succeeded in recording video output by reading from application's main window's device context but have no idea how to read the sound output of a game application.

i am working on windows and use Microsoft Visual studio and C++

Comment: Have you done some research (aka Google)?

Comment: @Tobimcnamobi no it is not a duplicate, hence he wants to read the output of one specific application

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to specifically capture the sound from a game. The video / sound capture utilities rely on a sound cards ability to "record what you hear" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way could be to create a virtual device the game uses. Then you can easily catch it.

Another possible way could be to enable and use the [Audio Loopback Device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And many others...

The 2 key questions you got to ask yourself are:

Do I need the caught sound track as fast as possible? (performance)

Do I need the very original output or is loop-back fine?

When you can answer those 2 questions, we may be able to provide you with more specific tools you can use.

Else we need to guess what you want.